# Как избавиться от RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, рекурсия

решаю задачу:
Алгоритм вычисления значения функции F(n), где n – целое число, задан следующими соотношениями:

```
F(n) = n, при n ≤ 5,
F(n) = n + F(n/5 + 1), когда n > 5 и делится на 5,
F(n) = n + F(n + 6) , когда n > 5 и не делится на 5.
Назовите минимальное значение n, для которого `F(n) > 1000.`
```

Постоянно выдает `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`
Как решить подобное?
Заранее спасибо

Мой код перебирает все в цикле значения n и вылетает с ошибкой

```
def f(n):
    if n <= 5:
        return n
    if n > 5 and n % 5 == 0:
        return n + f(n/5 + 1)
    if n > 5 and n % 5 != 0:
        return n + f(n + 6)

for n in range(1, 1000):
    if f(n) > 1000:
        print(n)
        break
```

Comment: Правильно написать рекурсию ) Нужен ваш код (наверняка забыли прописать условие выхода из рекурсии, `if n <= 5: return n`)

Comment: def f(n):
    if n <= 5:
        return n
    if n > 5 and n % 5 == 0:
        return n + f(n/5 + 1)
    if n > 5 and n % 5 != 0:
        return n + f(n + 6)

for n in range(1, 1000):
    if f(n) > 1000:
        print(n)
        break @OPTIMUSPRIME

Answer (score 2):

При `n = 6` алгоритм зацикливается. Вы полностью привели условие задачи?

```js
function f(n) {
  count++;
  console.log("n =", n, "step =", count);
  if (count > 20)
    return 0;

  if (n <= 5)
    return n;
  if (n > 5 && n % 5 == 0)
    return n + f(n / 5 + 1);
  if (n > 5 && n % 5 != 0)
    return n + f(n + 6);
}
var count = 0;
console.log(f(6));
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо было просто написать исключение для ошибки `RecursionError`

```
def f(n):
    if n <= 5:
        return n
    if n > 5 and n % 5 == 0:
        return n + f(n/5 + 1)
    if n > 5 and n % 5 != 0:
        return n + f(n + 6)

for n in range(1, 1000):
    try:
        if f(n) > 1000:
            print(n)
            break
    except RecursionError:
        print("fail")
```

всем спасибо за ответы!